# CakePHP - input box restricted with linked EmployeeID, from previous page

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I got 2 related tables, let say :
- employee, and
- family

they are both connected by the employeeID as the primary and foreign key. I believe you all understand this standard condition.

I have already created all the models, controllers and views using the "cake bake".
Everything is okay, until when i want to add new family.
The scenario is listed below :

-- on the front page, all employees are listed, along with their VIEW, EDIT and DELETE button, each.
-- i click the VIEW button on one of the employee, let say employee MAZANDRE with employeeID 123
-- i will see the detail of MAZANDRE
-- below the detail, there is one button to ADD NEW FAMILY.
-- i modified the ADD NEW FAMILY hyperlink into this

```
<li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('New Family'), array('controller' => 'families', 'action' => 'add', $employee['Employee']['id'])); ?> </li>
```

-- then i also modified the add function in FamiliesController like this

```
    public function add($id = null) {
    $this->Family->id = $id;
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Family->create();
        if ($this->Family->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The Family has been saved'));
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The Family could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }

    $employees = $this->Family->Employee->findById($id);

    $this->set(compact('employees'));
}
```

-- then i click this ADD NEW FAMILY button
-- there is one dropdown box which list ALL the employee detail (id, name, dateofbirth, gender etc). 
the link shows http://x.x.x.x/hr/family/add/123

what i want is, the INPUTBOX should only list one name which is: MAZANDRE, and cannot be modified (disabled)
the original one is like this `echo $this->Form->input('employee_id')`
how should i do this ?

Appreciate your help guys :-)
Many thanks.

Regards,
Andri

Comment: please paste your code of action 'add' from family controller.

Comment: hi ansari, thank you. i modified my questions because i got some clues ;-) need a little bit touch.

Comment: it is actually redirecting to index action after adding onew Family, this is where you are getting complete list. You need to show index function also

Comment: i just add another information. echo $this->Form->input('employee_id').  could you please more specific ansari ?

Comment: you want to see only Mazandre in list right ? for that you need to show code of action "index" in family controller as you posted for add action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

voila !
I got my own answer.
I just check this URL [cakephp: find statement with 'contain'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698069/cakephp-find-statement-with-contain/8699222#8699222)

But thanks to Moyed Ansari, and also user2484796

I just put these code
on my FamiliesController
 
the line
`$employees = $this->Family->Employee->findById($id);`

replaced by
 `$employees = $this->Family->Employee->find('list',array('conditions' => array('Employee.id' => $id)));`

that's it ! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
  echo $this->Form->input('employee_id',array('readonly','value' => 'MAZANDRE'));
```

This will make the input field a readonly value and the value will be submitted through the form.

Comment: but the value should be different when i choose different employee ofcourse. if you do that way, every employee detail i click, will result the same value = MAZANDRE. it shoudl be different. thank you for your help :-)